# Using npm to install puppetteer gives Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer/internal/node/install.js'

Tags: npm, puppeteer

Trying to install puppeteer on Centos 7

```
npm i puppeteer

> puppeteer@19.4.1 postinstall /mypath/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer/internal/node/install.js'

Require stack:
- /mypath/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mypath/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js:38:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/mypath/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js'
  ]
}
```

It doesn't seem to have downloaded anything into the node_modules/ directory, which I think "npm i" should do, and all of the tutorials I have read do not ask you perform any action or download, before running the npm command.

What do I need to do, to make this install puppeteer?  (with chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting this error because my node version was too old (version 10) but fixed it by switching to version 16.

To fix this I used `nvm` from the command line as follows:

```
nvm use 16
nvm alias default 16
```